# eliminate instance variable in partial, getting nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial that has an instance variable in it. I am trying to eliminate this instance variable because instance variables are not suppose to be in partials. When I try eliminating it I am getting errors

partial with instance variable

```
<%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##{@idea.first_color_hex}' >#
{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %>
```

partial without instance variable

```
<%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##{idea.first_color_hex}' >#
{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %>
```

getting nil for idea

what I tried:

creating this variable as an object

```
<%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##{f.object.idea.first_color_hex}' >#
{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %>
```

getting nil for first_color_hex

Also tried creating an if then statement

```
<% if f.object.idea.nil? %>
    <%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##{@idea.first_color_hex}' >#
    {image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %>
<%else%>
    <%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##{f.object.idea.first_color_hex}'   
     >#{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %>
<%end%>
```

but there is still an instance variable there. Not sure what the if should be

ideas model:
     class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 attr_accessor :product_line_tokens

has_many :artworks, -> { order('dimensions ASC') }
has_and_belongs_to_many :colors, -> { order('name asc').uniq }
has_and_belongs_to_many :imprintables, -> { uniq }, :join_table => :imprintables_ideas
has_and_belongs_to_many :stores, -> { order('name asc').uniq }, :join_table => 
 :stores_ideas
has_and_belongs_to_many :taxonomies, -> { order('name asc').order('store_id').uniq }, 
 :join_table => :taxonomies_ideas
has_and_belongs_to_many :product_lines, :join_table => "product_lines_ideas"
belongs_to :default_artwork, :class_name => "Artwork", :foreign_key => 
 :default_artwork_id
belongs_to :copywriter, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :copywriter_id
belongs_to :artist, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :artist_id
has_many :mockups

 def first_color_hex
    if colors.count == 0
        return nil
    else
        return colors[0].hex_code
    end
 end
```

partial tag:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'art_show', :locals => {:idea => @idea} %>
```

Comment: Please post your call to render the partial. Should look something like this: `<%= render :my_partial, idea: @idea %>`

Comment: why can't instance variables be in partials?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I eliminated the instance variable with if else

```
<% if f.object.idea.nil? %>
      <%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: none' >#
{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe %><br />
 <%else%>
      <%= f.label :file, "<span style='background-color: ##
{f.object.idea.first_color_hex}' >#{image_tag(f.object.file.url(:icon))}</span>".html_safe 
%><br />
  <%end%>
```